# How to have a DataGrid with two ButtonColumns in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have an ASP DataGrid with a ButtonColumn in it, like this:-

```
<asp:DataGrid id="gradesGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="true"
              runat="server"
              OnSelectedIndexChanged="GradesDataGridSelectedCallback">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonColumn HeaderText=""
                          ButtonType="LinkButton"
                          Text="Graph"
                          CommandName="Select">
        </asp:ButtonColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

and this works perfectly; when the button column is clicked, the `GradesDataGridSelectedCallback` function is invoked and all is marvellous. I now need to add a second button column to this data grid, to perform a different function related to the grid item. I add the extra code:-

```
<asp:ButtonColumn HeaderText=""
                  ButtonType="LinkButton"
                  Text="Display"
                  CommandName="NewFunction">
</asp:ButtonColumn>
```

This displays as expected but clicking the second button (although it causes a post-back), doesn't invoke the `GradesDataGridSelectedCallback` function. The question is, how to I wire up this second ButtonColumn to a particular function in the C# codebehind?

Alternatively, if I specify the button column so:-

```
<asp:ButtonColumn HeaderText=""
                  ButtonType="LinkButton"
                  Text="Display"
                  CommandName="Select">
</asp:ButtonColumn>
```

then the `GradesDataGridSelectedCallback` does get invoked, but I can't see any way of determining which ButtonColumn was clicked. Is there a way, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="GradesDataGridSelectedCallback"
```

Use

```
OnItemCommand ="GradesDataGridSelectedCallback"
```

And define your `GradesDataGridSelectedCallback` as

```
Protected void GradesDataGridSelectedCallback(Object source , DataGridCommandEventArgs e)

End Sub
```

Checking `e.CommandName` would give you indication of which button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Use **ItemCommand** event rather than  **OnSelectedIndexChanged** It will fire for everybutton.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dtGrg" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
                            onitemcommand="dtGrg_ItemCommand">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:ButtonColumn HeaderText="" ButtonType="LinkButton"  Text="Graph"  CommandName="Select">
                                </asp:ButtonColumn>
                                <asp:ButtonColumn HeaderText="" ButtonType="LinkButton" Text="Display" CommandName="NewFunction" >
                                </asp:ButtonColumn>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:DataGrid>
```

---

```
protected void dtGrg_ItemCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "NewFunction")
            { 
             //Your Code Here :
            }
             if (e.CommandName == "Select")
            {
                //Your Code Here :
            }
        }
```

**OnSelectedIndexChanged** will only work for select button.